# App crashes on launch after Moengage implemented

Tags: android

App Crashes when Moengage is initialized.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   getInstanceId()Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId' appears
>   in /data/app/com.morecustomersapp-1/base.apk:classes3.dex)
>           at com.moengage.firebase.PushHandlerImpl.getPushToken(PushHandlerImpl.java:63)
>           at com.moengage.firebase.PushHandlerImpl.registerForPushToken(PushHandlerImpl.java:52)
>           at com.moengage.pushbase.push.MoEPushWorker.registerForPush(MoEPushWorker.java:214)
>           at com.moengage.pushbase.push.MoEPushWorker.handlePushRegistrationFallback(MoEPushWorker.java:261)
>           at com.moengage.pushbase.push.MoEPushWorker.onHandleIntent(MoEPushWorker.java:109)
>           at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 2019-04-01 02:58:31.843 23134-23499/com.morecustomersapp
>   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   getInstanceId()Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId' appears
>   in /data/app/com.morecustomersapp-1/base.apk:classes3.dex)
>           at com.moengage.firebase.PushHandlerImpl.getPushToken(PushHandlerImpl.java:63)
>           at com.moengage.firebase.PushHandlerImpl.registerForPushToken(PushHandlerImpl.java:52)
>           at com.moengage.pushbase.push.MoEPushWorker.registerForPush(MoEPushWorker.java:214)
>           at com.moengage.pushbase.push.MoEPushWorker.handlePushRegistrationFallback(MoEPushWorker.java:261)
>           at com.moengage.pushbase.push.MoEPushWorker.onHandleIntent(MoEPushWorker.java:109)
>           at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Module level gradle:

```
implementation ('com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:9.3.01') {
    exclude group: 'com.moengage', module: 'moe-location-lib'
}
```

Project level gradle

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
 classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

Application Class:

```
public class AppConfig extends Application implements PushManager.OnTokenReceivedListener, OnAppBackgroundListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MoEngage moEngage = new MoEngage.Builder(this, getResources().getString(R.string.mo_engage_app_id))
                .setLogLevel(Logger.VERBOSE)
                .enableLogsForSignedBuild()
                .setNotificationSmallIcon(
                        R.drawable.ic_notification_holo)
                .setNotificationLargeIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .enableLocationServices()
                .build();
        MoEngage.initialise(moEngage);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("demoapp", 0);
        boolean existing = false;
        if (preferences.getBoolean("has_sent_install", false)) {
            if (preferences.getBoolean("existing", false)) {
                existing = true;
            }
            MoEHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setExistingUser(existing);
            preferences.edit().putBoolean("has_sent_install", true).apply();
            preferences.edit().putBoolean("existing", true).apply();
        }
        PushManager.getInstance().setTokenObserver(this);


        MoEHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerAppBackgroundListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void goingToBackground() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenReceived(String token) {
        Log.d("MoEngageDemo", "onTokenReceived: " + token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. But luckily found the solution for this

### Solution 1

```
val moEngage = MoEngage.Builder(this, BuildConfig.MOENGAGE_ID)
            .enableSegmentIntegration()
            .setLogLevel(Logger.VERBOSE)
            .build()
MoEngage.initialise(moEngage)
```

I think during initialization of MoEngage you could have forget to add `enableSegmentIntegration()`

### Solution 2

Add these dependency in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
```